# Creating double from strings

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, double

first of all totally new here, had a search but maybe I don't know what I'm looking for.

Basically I've made a simple exchange rate app that has a fixed exchange rate.

You type in the text field your currency and it converts it for you.

I'm struggling with creating the result from the textfield x my exchange rate. I think it's something to do with forcing a double but i've tried so many ways.

Thanks in advance

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

let exchangeRate = 5.99


@IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

@IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {
    display.text = (textField.text * exchangeRate)



}
```

Comment: Use display.text =("\ (textField.text * exchangeRate)")

Comment: Hi @Gagan_iOS. I think you were close. i had to put parentheses around both variables individually.

However now I get 

Optional("11.2") * 5.99

As an output for my label. any ideas?

Comment: You have to unwrap the label's text with `if let text = textField.text`.

Comment: Hi @keithbhunter That and your code below just throws up errors at me. I'm sure it's simple. I will keep trying things, it's good for the brain

Comment: ohhk, My fault..use if let valueDouble=Double(textField.text)  display.text =("\ (valueDouble * exchangeRate)")

Answer (score 2):

You can cast the `String` to a `Double` using an initializer and unwrapping, and then update the text field with the new value.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let exchangeRate = 5.99

    @IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {
        if let text = textField.text {
            if let input = Double(text) {
                display.text = String(input * exchangeRange)
            }
        }
    }
}
```